# \markboth-header on wrong page

Tags: xetex, header-footer

I have the following problem: I want to typeset a Bible. The header should show the first and the last verse on each page. So I defined a new command `\newcommand{\wers}[4]{{\markboth{#2}{#1}#3\,#4\par}}`, marking each verse like this: `\wers{Book\,1,1}{1,1}{1.}{text}`. Using **XeLateX** the output sometimes looks the expected way. But very often it looks like this: Last printed verse on page: Mc 1,19, but header shows 1,20. Or: First printed verse on page: Mc 1,19, but header shows Mc 1,18. I tried to make the example as minimal as possible. But I use the original text, because it seems, that the problem depends on how long each line is.

```
\documentclass[headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}
% original-question-version: \newcommand{\wers}[4]{{\markboth{#2}{#1}#3\,#4\par}}
\newcommand{\wers}[4]{{#3\,#4\markboth{#2}{#1}\par}}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\rightmark–\leftmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,1}{1,1}{1.}{We zachopjenku stwori Bog njebjo a~zemju.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,2}{1,2}{2.}{A~ta zemja beso pusta a~prozna, a~wono beso sma na tej dlymi; a~ten Bozy Duch zmawowaso se na tych wodach.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,3}{1,3}{3.}{A~Bog zaso: wono buzi swetlo. A~wono bu swetlo.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,4}{1,4}{4.}{A~Bog wizeso, az to swetlo dobre beso. Ga rozdzeli Bog to swetlo wot teje samnosci,}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,5}{1,5}{5.}{A~gronjaso tomu swetlu zen, a~tej samnosci noc. Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten predny zen.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,6}{1,6}{6.}{A~Bog zaso: wono buzi twardosc mjazy tymi wodami; a~ta sama buzi jadno rozdzelenje mjazy tymi wodami.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,7}{1,7}{7.}{Ga wugotowa Bog tu twardosc, a~rozdzeli tu wodu spozy teje twardosci, wot teje wody nad teju twardoscu. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,8}{1,8}{8.}{A~Bog namjeni tu twardosc njebjo. Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten drugi zen.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,9}{1,9}{9.}{A~Bog zaso: wono se gromaz ta woda spozy njebja na wosebne mesta, aby se to suche wizelo. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,10}{1,10}{10.}{A~Bog nagroni tomu suchemu zemja, a~to zgromazenje tych wodow pomjeni won morjo. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,11}{1,11}{11.}{A~Bog zaso: ta zemja daj wuschojzis tsawu a~zelinu, kotaraz se wobsemjenijo; a~plodne bomy, aby kuzdy po swojom rodu plody psinjasl, a~mel swojo semje sam psi se na zemi. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,12}{1,12}{12.}{A~ta zemja da wuschojzowas tsawu a~zelinu, kotaraz se wobsemjeni, kuzde po swojom rodu, a~bomy, kotarez plody mewachu, a~swojo semje sami psi se mejachu, kuzdy po swojom rodu. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,13}{1,13}{13.}{Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten tsesi zen.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,14}{1,14}{14.}{A~Bog zaso: dasi swetla na tej twardosci togo njebja bywaju, kotarez rozdzelili zen a~noc, a~dali znamjenja, casy, dny a~leta,}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,15}{1,15}{15.}{A~byli swetla na tej twardosci togo njebja, aby swesili na zemju. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,16}{1,16}{16.}{A~Bog wugotowa dwe wjelikej swetly; jadno wjelike swetlo, kotarez se nad tym dnjom knezylo, a~jadno malke swetlo, kenz se nad teju nocu knezylo, k~tomu tez gwezdy.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,17}{1,17}{17.}{A~Bog staji je na tu twardosc togo njebja, aby swetlo dawali na tu zemju,}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,18}{1,18}{18.}{A~se knezyli nad tym dnjom a~teju nocu, a~rozdzelili swetlo a~samnosc. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,19}{1,19}{19.}{Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten stworty zen.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,20}{1,20}{20.}{A~Bog zaso: wono se gibaj ta woda, az se wso wjersi wot zywych zwerjetow, a~wot ptaskow, kotarez na zemi spozy teje wusoknosci togo njebja letali.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,21}{1,21}{21.}{A~Bog stwori wjelike morske ryby, a~wsake zwerjeta, kenz we woze bydle, pleju a~se ploze, kuzde po swojom rodu, a~wsaku pjerinu, kuzdu po swojom rodu. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,22}{1,22}{22.}{A~Bog zognowaso jich, a~zaso: buzco plodne a~rozplozco se, a~napolnso tu wodu we morju; a~ta pjerina se rozploz na zemi.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,23}{1,23}{23.}{Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten pety zen.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,24}{1,24}{24.}{A~Bog zaso: ta zemja psinjas napredk zywych zwerjetow, kuzde po swojom rodu; zbozo, wuzence a~zwerjeta na zemi, kuzde po swojom rodu. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,25}{1,25}{25.}{A~Bog stwori te zwerjeta na zemi, kuzde po swojom rodu, a~to zbozo po swojom rodu, a~wsakich wuzencow po swojom rodu. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,26}{1,26}{26.}{A~Bog zaso: stwormy clowjekow, bildu, kotaraz nam rowna byla, kotarez se knezyli nad tymi rybami we morju, a~nad tymi ptaskami spozy njebja a~nad tym zbozom, a~nad teju celeju zemju, a~wsyknymi wuzencami, kenz po zemi laze.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,27}{1,27}{27.}{A~Bog stwori togo clowjeka sebje k~rownosci, k~rownosci Bozej stwori won jogo; a~stwori jeju jadnogo muskego a~jadnu zensku.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,28}{1,28}{28.}{A~Bog zognowaso jeju, a~zaso k~nima: buztej plodnej a~rozploztej se, a~napolntej tu zemju, a~cyntej sebje ju podejspjonu, a~kneztej se nad tymi rybami we morju, a~nad tymi ptaskami spozy njebja, a~nad wsyknymi zwerjetami, kenz po zemi laze.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,29}{1,29}{29.}{A~Bog zaso: lej, ja som wama dal wsake zele, kotarez se wobsemjenijo, na celej zemi, a~wsake plodne bomy, a~bomy, kenz se wobsemjenje, k~waju jezi;}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,30}{1,30}{30.}{Ale wsomu zbozu na zemi, a~wsyknym ptaskam spozy njebja, a~wsyknym wuzencam, kotarez zywe su na zemi, aby woni wsakoraku zelinu jedli. A~wono se tak stanu.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,1,31}{1,31}{31.}{A~Bog gledaso na wso, coz won wugotowal beso; a~lej, wono beso wjelgickano dobre. Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten sesty zen.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,1}{2,1}{1.}{Tak bustej dogotowanej njebjo a~zemja ze wsyknymi stworbami.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,2}{2,2}{2.}{A~z~takim dokoncowa Bog na sedymy zen swoje statki, kotarez won zgotowa; a~wotpocywaso na sedymy zen wot wsyknych swojich statkow, kotarez won wugotowa;}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,3}{2,3}{3.}{A~zognowaso ten sedymy zen a~wuswesi jen, togodla, az won na ten samy beso wotpocywal wot wsyknych swojich statkow, kotarez Bog stwori a~wucyni.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,4}{2,4}{4.}{Tak stej njebjo a~zemja se chopilej, gaz wonej stworjonej bustej, we tom casu, ako Bog ten Knez zemju a~njebjo zgotowa;}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,5}{2,5}{5.}{A~wsake bomy na poli, kotarez pjerwjej nikula njebechu byli na zemi, a~wsakorake zele na poli, kotarez pjerwjej zednje njebeso roslo. Pseto Bog ten Knez njebeso hysci zednogo desca dal padas na zemju, a~wono njebeso zeden clowjek, kenz bu rolu zelal.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,6}{2,6}{6.}{Ale kurjawa zeso gorjej ze zemje, a~namaca wsu zemju.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,7}{2,7}{7.}{A~Bog ten Knez wugotowa togo clowjeka z~gruzle zemje, a~dunu jomu zywy dych do jogo nosa. A~tak bu ten clowjek jadna zywa dusa.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,8}{2,8}{8.}{A~Bog ten Knez wugotowa jadno gumno we Edenje, k~zajtsomu, a~pusci togo clowjeka do njogo, kotaregoz won beso stworil.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,9}{2,9}{9.}{A~Bog ten Knez da narosc ze zemje wsake bomy lubosnje k~wugledanju, a~derje k~jezi, a~ten bom togo zywjenja srjejz gumna, a~ten bom togo wuznasa dobrego a~zlego.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,10}{2,10}{10.}{A~z~Edena bezaso reka to gumno k~macanju, a~rozdzeli se tam do styrich wosebnych wodow.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,11}{2,11}{11.}{Tej prednej gronje Pizon, ta bezy wokolo teje zemje Hevila, a~tam namakajo se zloto.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,12}{2,12}{12.}{A~to zloto teje zemje jo ksasne, a~tamkor jo Bedelion k~namakanju, a~ten drogi kamjen Onyks.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,13}{2,13}{13.}{Tej drugej woze gronje Gihon, ta bezy wokolo celeje Morskeje zemje.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,14}{2,14}{14.}{Tej tsesej woze gronje Hidekel, ta bezy predku Asyriskeje. Ta stworta woda jo ten Frat.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,15}{2,15}{15.}{A~Bog ten Knez weze togo clowjeka, a~pusci jogo do togo gumna Eden, aby won jo zelal a~wobzwarnowal.}
\wers{1\,Mojzas\,2,16}{2,16}{16.}{A~Bog ten Knez psikaza tomu clowjekoju, a~zaso: jez wot wsakich bomow we tom gumnje;}    
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, I cannot play with your snippet because it contains special characters, but I'd true `\newcommand{\wers}[4]{{#3\,#4\markboth{#2}{#1}#3\,#4\par}}`.

Comment: Thank you, marmot. I am shure, this is the right direction. I changed your code to `\newcommand{\wers}[4]{{#3\,#4\markboth{#2}{#1}\par}}`. Now it is perfect with all verses, that are complet on one page. But there still remains a problem with these, which start at one page and end on the next. The header shows the last complete verse, not the last verse starting on the page. It is the same with the new page: The header starts with the verse, which started on the old page. Is there a possibility to fix this?

Comment: Dear __marmot__, I cut out all special characters, maybe you are able to play with the code now. I would be glad, if there would be a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'll be busy now, and hope that someone else finds a solution. (If not, I'll try later, I'll try to define an environment for the verses...)

Comment: Marmot, you pointed me in the right direction. It seems, the solution is `\newcommand{\wers}[4]{{\markright{#1}#3\,\markleft{#2}#4\par}}` I do not see any problems now. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Which Slavic language is this document typeset in?

Comment: Why do you split your two arguments? I would have done something like `\markboth{#1-#2}{#1-#2}`?

Comment: you have the `\markboth` at the end of the verse not the beginning so if it breaks over a page you will get the page the verse ends on, not the page it starts on, also there is no need to have so many arguments, you are just specifying the same number multiple times.

Comment: @marmot why do you suggest an extra group here? The mark is unaffected by grouping.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure. I wanted to do a group with counters etc. because much of the arguments of the `\wers` command seems to be redundant, and, arguably, an environment seems to provide cleaner structuring. But Ulrike Fischer was faster anyway.

Comment: @Mico: It is Lower Sorbian (but I removed the diacritics).

Answer (score 2):

I would try to avoid to input all the values and names so often. It only makes the input tedious and error prone:

```
\documentclass[headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}
\newcommand{\wers}[1]{\par 
 \stepcounter{verscnt}%
 \theverscnt.%
 \markboth{\thebookcnt.\,\bookname~\thebookcnt,\theverscnt}%
          {\thebookcnt.\,\bookname~\thebookcnt,\theverscnt}%
 \,#1\par}
\newcommand\bookname{}
\newcommand\newbook[1]{\stepcounter{bookcnt}\def\bookname{#1}}
\newcounter{bookcnt}
\newcounter{verscnt}[bookcnt]

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\rightmark\,--\,\leftmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\newbook{Mojzas}
\wers{We zachopjenku stwori Bog njebjo a~zemju.}
\wers{A~ta zemja beso pusta a~prozna, a~wono beso sma na tej dlymi; a~ten Bozy Duch zmawowaso se na tych wodach.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: wono buzi swetlo. A~wono bu swetlo.}
\wers{A~Bog wizeso, az to swetlo dobre beso. Ga rozdzeli Bog to swetlo wot teje samnosci,}
\wers{A~gronjaso tomu swetlu zen, a~tej samnosci noc. Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten predny zen.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: wono buzi twardosc mjazy tymi wodami; a~ta sama buzi jadno rozdzelenje mjazy tymi wodami.}
\wers{Ga wugotowa Bog tu twardosc, a~rozdzeli tu wodu spozy teje twardosci, wot teje wody nad teju twardoscu. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{A~Bog namjeni tu twardosc njebjo. Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten drugi zen.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: wono se gromaz ta woda spozy njebja na wosebne mesta, aby se to suche wizelo. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{A~Bog nagroni tomu suchemu zemja, a~to zgromazenje tych wodow pomjeni won morjo. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: ta zemja daj wuschojzis tsawu a~zelinu, kotaraz se wobsemjenijo; a~plodne bomy, aby kuzdy po swojom rodu plody psinjasl, a~mel swojo semje sam psi se na zemi. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{A~ta zemja da wuschojzowas tsawu a~zelinu, kotaraz se wobsemjeni, kuzde po swojom rodu, a~bomy, kotarez plody mewachu, a~swojo semje sami psi se mejachu, kuzdy po swojom rodu. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten tsesi zen.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: dasi swetla na tej twardosci togo njebja bywaju, kotarez rozdzelili zen a~noc, a~dali znamjenja, casy, dny a~leta,}
\wers{A~byli swetla na tej twardosci togo njebja, aby swesili na zemju. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{A~Bog wugotowa dwe wjelikej swetly; jadno wjelike swetlo, kotarez se nad tym dnjom knezylo, a~jadno malke swetlo, kenz se nad teju nocu knezylo, k~tomu tez gwezdy.}
\wers{A~Bog staji je na tu twardosc togo njebja, aby swetlo dawali na tu zemju,}
\wers{A~se knezyli nad tym dnjom a~teju nocu, a~rozdzelili swetlo a~samnosc. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten stworty zen.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: wono se gibaj ta woda, az se wso wjersi wot zywych zwerjetow, a~wot ptaskow, kotarez na zemi spozy teje wusoknosci togo njebja letali.}
\wers{A~Bog stwori wjelike morske ryby, a~wsake zwerjeta, kenz we woze bydle, pleju a~se ploze, kuzde po swojom rodu, a~wsaku pjerinu, kuzdu po swojom rodu. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{A~Bog zognowaso jich, a~zaso: buzco plodne a~rozplozco se, a~napolnso tu wodu we morju; a~ta pjerina se rozploz na zemi.}
\wers{Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten pety zen.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: ta zemja psinjas napredk zywych zwerjetow, kuzde po swojom rodu; zbozo, wuzence a~zwerjeta na zemi, kuzde po swojom rodu. A~wono se stanu tak.}
\wers{A~Bog stwori te zwerjeta na zemi, kuzde po swojom rodu, a~to zbozo po swojom rodu, a~wsakich wuzencow po swojom rodu. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso. A~Bog wizeso, az to dobre beso.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: stwormy clowjekow, bildu, kotaraz nam rowna byla, kotarez se knezyli nad tymi rybami we morju, a~nad tymi ptaskami spozy njebja a~nad tym zbozom, a~nad teju celeju zemju, a~wsyknymi wuzencami, kenz po zemi laze.}
\wers{A~Bog stwori togo clowjeka sebje k~rownosci, k~rownosci Bozej stwori won jogo; a~stwori jeju jadnogo muskego a~jadnu zensku.}
\wers{A~Bog zognowaso jeju, a~zaso k~nima: buztej plodnej a~rozploztej se, a~napolntej tu zemju, a~cyntej sebje ju podejspjonu, a~kneztej se nad tymi rybami we morju, a~nad tymi ptaskami spozy njebja, a~nad wsyknymi zwerjetami, kenz po zemi laze.}
\wers{A~Bog zaso: lej, ja som wama dal wsake zele, kotarez se wobsemjenijo, na celej zemi, a~wsake plodne bomy, a~bomy, kenz se wobsemjenje, k~waju jezi;}
\wers{Ale wsomu zbozu na zemi, a~wsyknym ptaskam spozy njebja, a~wsyknym wuzencam, kotarez zywe su na zemi, aby woni wsakoraku zelinu jedli. A~wono se tak stanu.}
\wers{A~Bog gledaso na wso, coz won wugotowal beso; a~lej, wono beso wjelgickano dobre. Ga bu z~wjacora a~ze zajtsego ten sesty zen.}
\newbook{Mojzas}
\wers{Tak bustej dogotowanej njebjo a~zemja ze wsyknymi stworbami.}
\wers{A~z~takim dokoncowa Bog na sedymy zen swoje statki, kotarez won zgotowa; a~wotpocywaso na sedymy zen wot wsyknych swojich statkow, kotarez won wugotowa;}
\wers{A~zognowaso ten sedymy zen a~wuswesi jen, togodla, az won na ten samy beso wotpocywal wot wsyknych swojich statkow, kotarez Bog stwori a~wucyni.}
\wers{Tak stej njebjo a~zemja se chopilej, gaz wonej stworjonej bustej, we tom casu, ako Bog ten Knez zemju a~njebjo zgotowa;}
\wers{A~wsake bomy na poli, kotarez pjerwjej nikula njebechu byli na zemi, a~wsakorake zele na poli, kotarez pjerwjej zednje njebeso roslo. Pseto Bog ten Knez njebeso hysci zednogo desca dal padas na zemju, a~wono njebeso zeden clowjek, kenz bu rolu zelal.}
\wers{Ale kurjawa zeso gorjej ze zemje, a~namaca wsu zemju.}
\wers{A~Bog ten Knez wugotowa togo clowjeka z~gruzle zemje, a~dunu jomu zywy dych do jogo nosa. A~tak bu ten clowjek jadna zywa dusa.}
\wers{A~Bog ten Knez wugotowa jadno gumno we Edenje, k~zajtsomu, a~pusci togo clowjeka do njogo, kotaregoz won beso stworil.}
\wers{A~Bog ten Knez da narosc ze zemje wsake bomy lubosnje k~wugledanju, a~derje k~jezi, a~ten bom togo zywjenja srjejz gumna, a~ten bom togo wuznasa dobrego a~zlego.}
\wers{A~z~Edena bezaso reka to gumno k~macanju, a~rozdzeli se tam do styrich wosebnych wodow.}
\wers{Tej prednej gronje Pizon, ta bezy wokolo teje zemje Hevila, a~tam namakajo se zloto.}
\wers{A~to zloto teje zemje jo ksasne, a~tamkor jo Bedelion k~namakanju, a~ten drogi kamjen Onyks.}
\wers{Tej drugej woze gronje Gihon, ta bezy wokolo celeje Morskeje zemje.}
\wers{Tej tsesej woze gronje Hidekel, ta bezy predku Asyriskeje. Ta stworta woda jo ten Frat.}
\wers{A~Bog ten Knez weze togo clowjeka, a~pusci jogo do togo gumna Eden, aby won jo zelal a~wobzwarnowal.}
\wers{A~Bog ten Knez psikaza tomu clowjekoju, a~zaso: jez wot wsakich bomow we tom gumnje;}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```